# Scikit Learn - Working with datasets

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

Reading through some stackoverflow questions and I could not find what I was looking for, at least, I didn't think it was when I read various posts.

I have some Training data set up like described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files)
So, I am using sklearn.datasets.load_files to read those it as it was a perfect match on set up.

BUT my files are tsv as bag of words already (aka each line is a word and it's frequency count separated by a tab).

To be honest, I am not sure how to proceed.  The data pulled in by load_files is set up as a list where each element is the contents of each file, including the new line characters. I am not even 100% sure how the Bunch data type is tracking which files belong to which classifier folder.

I have worked with scikit-learn before with tsvs, but it was a single tsv file that had all the data so i used pandas to read it in and then used numpy.array to fetch what I needed from it, which is one of the things I attempted to do, but I am not sure how to do it with multiple files where the classifier is the folder name, as in that single tsv file i worked with before, each line of training data was individually

Some help on getting the data to a format that is useable for training classifiers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this part: "To use text files in a scikit-learn classification or clustering algorithm, you will need to use the sklearn.feature_extraction.text module to build a feature extraction transformer that suits your problem."

Comment: I have.... but that relies on raw data i'm pretty sure... which I don't have.

Comment: You can write a custom feature extractor which will extract you features from the data set. It is actually quite simple to use if you take the time to read the docs. Look at subclassing `BaseEstimator` to extract the feature you want.

Comment: I am not sure how this gets my data into the correct format.  The BaseEstimator Class doesn't look like it's for feature extraction.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `TransformerMixin`.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the files and read them, to create a list of dictionaries where each dictionary will contain the features and the frequencies of each document. Assume the file 1.txt:

```
import codecs
corpus = []
#make a loop over the files here and repeat the following
f = codecs.open("1.txt", encoding='utf8').read().splitlines()
corpus.append({line.split("\t")[0]:line.split("\t")[1] for line in f})
#exit the loop here
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec=DictVectorizer()
X=vec.fit_transform(measurements)
```

You can find more here for [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer)